# XPath select text after a category text without class

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

i use HtmlAgilityPack.
i want take (title1 and title2 only in Title: part) or (number1 and number2 only in Number: part).

```
<div>
    <span class="dark_text">Title:</span>
          <a href="linktitle1" title="title1">title1</a>,<a href="link title2" title="title2">title2</a> 
</div>
//other part same xml
<div>
    <span class="dark_text">Number:</span>
          <a href="linknumber1" title="number1">number1</a>,<a href="linknumber2" title="number2">number2</a> 
</div>
```

i try this code:

```
HtmlNodeCollection summary = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div/a[not(@id)]");
MessageBox.Show(summary.Count.ToString());
for (int i = 0; i < summary.Count; i++)
{
      MessageBox.Show(summary[i].InnerText.ToString());
}
```

but the messagebox show all of them(title1,title2,number1,number2). i dont have a clue to take just 1 part category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter parent `div` by child `span` content, for example, the following should return title1, title2 :

```
//div[span='Title:']/a[not(@id)]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/x4VgiJg4B)</kbd>**